# Cast "Accounting" formatted numbers as text in Excel

Tags: excel, formatting, format

Here's the deal.  I'm using a code-based advanced filter to do a database search.  The criteria (as generated by the code) treats all data as text and appends a * to the front and back end of anything entered to facilitate partial lookups.

One of my fields (just one, in the middle of the data, and indistinguishable otherwise) is formatted as "Accounting".  I want to format it as text so that it is query-able.  But when I use the TEXT() function to try and format it (as I do in any other case where I need numbers stored as text), it won't accept "Accounting" as one of the presets.  And furthermore, if I attempt to copy-paste the format from Excel's own custom formats form like so: _(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* "-"??*);*(@_), then I get a #VALUE error in the cell.

By selectively trimming that format string I've gotten to where it no longer presents an error, but cannot get the numbers in the column to align on the decimal (which is the point of Accounting format).

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the #VALUE error because the format string has double quotes in it. If you use

```
=TEXT(B2,"_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)")
```

with the double quotes escaped (by doubling them) you won't get the error. But you won't get the desired result. There are some subtle differences between number formats and what the TEXT function will produce. I don't know what they all are, but this is one.

One option you have is to write your own function. This function will convert the accounting formatted number into a string and preserve the white space between the currency symbol and the first number.

```
Public Function GetRealText(Cell As Range) As String

    Application.Volatile
    GetRealText = Cell.Cells(1).Text

End Function
```

There is a catch, though. If you resize a column, the Range.Text property will change, but this function will not update automatically. Even though it's Volatile, a column width change won't trigger a recalc. You'd have to recalc manually or something else would have to trigger it.

Comment: This is definitely *a* solution.  More than I was hoping for, but less than I wanted.  I ended up just right-registering the column to line things up and using your double quote solution above to make the format work.  Thanks.  The $ symbol wasn't essential anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a number, date or any value as text by using the `'` prefix:

```
Cells(1, 1) = "'" & MyNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the formula times 1 and then the format cell containing the formula as Accounting

```
Cell A1 =5000
=TEXT(A1,"$#,##0.00") gives you currency.
=TEXT(A1,"$#,##0.00")*1 now it's back to a number and displays as your cell format. Format as Accounting
```